# Can I set the access authority to the folder(Tridion) connected by WebDAV , apart from authorization of Tridion?

Tags: 2013, webdav, authorization

I want to do following operation.

when the specific user access the folder(Tridion) using WebDAV, I apply access authority(read, write and so on) to the user **apart from authorization of Tridion** (that is, using access authority of **IIS** ).

I know that I can build webdav server on windows and set the folder authority to each user by seting access authority of **IIS** .

but I don't know that I can set access authority of **IIS** to the folder of Tridion connected by WebDAV.

So, can I set the access authority to the folder(Tridion) connected by WebDAV , apart from authorization of Tridion  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL Tridion does not do its own authentication, that is delegated to IIS. The same thing counts for when you are accessing SDL Tridion through WebDAV, as the WebDAV server also authenticates the user via IIS.

After a user is authenticated, SDL Tridion handles authorization based on what is configured for that user. If the logged in user has no read rights to a Publication or Folder, he won't see it or be able to access it.

So simply put, the Tridion folder you talk about being connected by WebDAV is the access point  to the SDL Tridion WebDAV server. Getting access to that is handled by IIS authentication (provided the username is registered and enabled in SDL Tridion's user list), there is nothing different you can do to this (as it isn't a real folder, it is just represented as a folder in the explorer interface). Whatever is available inside the WebDAV folder is handled by SDL Tridion authorization for that user (there is no possibility to change authorization for a user in WebDAV specifically, what ever rights they have in the CME is what rights they have in WebDAV too).

Comment: Authentication: IIS; Authorization: Tridion, 
irrelevant of the interface you use to get to Tridion, that's how it's usually done (some exceptions in some SSO scenarios where authentication is delegated by IIS to something else)